# NSLayoutConstraint height equal to origin.x in storyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, storyboard

How do I create a layout constraint in storyboard that makes the height of my view equal to its origin.x?

I'm using the latest xcode and ios.
Also using swift, but the answer can be in Objective-C.

Comment: Does it have to be in the interface builder? You can do it programmatically

Comment: I think I am able to figure it out how to do in code, but I want in storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a helper view:

Put an helper view on left, with these constraints:

- left = superview left
- height: doesn't matter (10 or something so you can debug it)
- top: also doesn't matter

Set your main view with left from superview/top/width whatever you want.

Set constraints between these two views:

- left of mainView = right of your helper view (horizontal spacing)
- height of your main view = width of your helper view

something like this: (the blue is the helper...)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I also thought of that, but I want without creating another view that I don't need.

Comment: Cool, sounds legit. Although I don't think that one view (you can set it to hidden) will matter to your app :) Anyway I couldn't find a way to do it otherwise. Let me know if you do...

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz, I think this is probably the best way, but it would be helpful to know what you want to do with this view as far as moving or resizing it for the different editing states.

Answer (score 0):

You can't relate a height to a spacing constraint (in IB anyway, I haven't tried it in code). One way that will work in IB is to make the height relative to self.view's width and the origin.x relative to the self.view's trailing (for a view that's the full width of the screen, like a controller's self.view, the value of width and of trailing are the same). So, in this example I made the height 0.2 times the superview's width, and the leading edge of the view be at 0.2 times the superview trailing.

You make the height constraint by selecting the view and the superview, and choosing equal widths. You can then edit that to change it to height for your view, and change the multiplier to what you want.

[image]

You make the origin.x constraint by dragging from your view to the left side of the superview, and then editing that to change it to trailing (from leading) for the superview.

[image]

Comment: But how are the width and origin connected? When the origin changes, it doesn't affect its height. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @oren, no, you're not missing anything, this is not ideal for sure, but it's the only way I could think of that didn't use another view. I think your approach is better actually.